# Parse Server JS SDK -> Get Class whilst also getting Relation Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parse-server

I'm using a self hosted parse server and looking for help pulling data out correctly.

Basically i have a Class named Books and a Class names _User. In the _User table, i  have a column set up as a Parse Relation named UsersBooks to the Books Class.

A user object can assign Book objects into their relation when they own the book.

I'd like to get all the Books in a list whilst also checking the current Users' UsersBooks and if it exists in there, do something with it.

Does anyone have any idea how i would do this?

```js
async function getBooksIncludingUsersBooks() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var BooksObject = Parse.Object.extend("Books");
        var query = new Parse.Query(BooksObject );
        query.limit(1000);
        query.find().then((results) => {
            resolve(results);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            reject(error);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relations   have u read the docs on relations?  and pointers?   these should help u out

Answer (score 0):

To query the content of the relation, you need to get the relation object and use its `query` helper method:

```
const usersBooks = await user.relation('UsersBooks').query().find()
```

You can apply the usual filters, sortings, etc. to the query object before executing it with `find`.

Comment: Is there a super smart way to display the list of Books and UsersBooks in the same loop once we have the data? I'd like to basically add a check if the user already has it in their UsersBooks.

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you mean with "list of Books and UsersBooks"? Do you want _all_ Books  in your DB together with the books assigned to a user (via the relation)?  If it's that: you will need two queries, one querying the `Book` table, the other one as described in my answer, and run them in parallel using `Promise.all` (or `Parse.Promise.when`).